# Object disappearing when rotating camera in Blender 4

Tags: objects, 3d-view, camera

I have installed Blender 4 and after opening my previous file from v3 I got strange behavior about disappearing. Please, any idea how to fix this?

In those two images I just slightly rotated camera.

[image]

[image]

edit: tried to change clip start distance and it broke it
[image]

Comment: Might be because of ur clip distance, try to lower it and check

Comment: tried to change it, see image in edit. But, when I set clip start to 0.001 m and clip end to 1000 m it seems fixed. So I had probably big values there.

Comment: yes, if u're modelling a flat or bulding you would probably be fine with 0.1 start and 1000 m end clip

Comment: Thank you. I probably set it far, because of sun, it was too bright so I was playing with it.

Comment: @Dawe What does the sun have to do with clipping distance?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann nothing probably, I was just playing around with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is introduced when the clipping value is too big.

It can be found here in View:
[image]

With these settings it works perfectly:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.